# looping through data table to get two specifics values from each row

Tags: c#, oracle, datatable

I 'm trying to loop through a `datatable` and print out the values of the

- 0,
- 1 and
- 4th cell of each row,

And it feels like this should be working but I'm probably messing up the loop somehow.

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
 {
      for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[0].ColumnName + " ");
          Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[0].ToString() + " ");
          Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[1].ColumnName + " ");
          Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[1].ToString() + " ");
          Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[4].ColumnName + " ");
          Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[4].ToString() + " ");
       }
 }
```

The above code gives me this error:

> The system cannot execute the specified program.

Comment: Well for starters you only need either the `foreach` or the `for` loop. You don't need both.

Comment: If you want just values, you probably can just go `foreach (var dr in dt.Rows) Console.WriteLine($"{dr[0]} - {dr[1]} - {dr[4]}");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to surround your `for` loop with a `foreach` loop on the Rows. (You are not using the `dr` at all)

```cs
for (int idx = 0; idx < dt.Rows.Count; idx++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[0].ColumnName + " ");
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[idx].ItemArray[0] + " ");
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[1].ColumnName + " ");
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[idx].ItemArray[1] + " ");
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[4].ColumnName + " ");
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[idx].ItemArray[4] + " ");
}
```

A bit more generic version:

```cs
int[] columnIndexes = new[] { 0, 1, 4 };
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dt.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
{
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnIndexes.Length; columnIndex++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[columnIndex].ColumnName + " ");
        Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[rowIndex].ItemArray[columnIndex] + " ");
    }
}
```

---

If you want to iterate through the Rows collection with foreach then you can do but it is a bit more trickier.

DataTable's Rows property is a [DataRowCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection?view=netcore-3.1). It exposes a `GetEnumerator` method, which is essential for the `foreach` loop.

```cs
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    //dr does not provide you direct access to the ColumnName
}
```

You can't access the ColumnName from the DataRow directly. All need to do is to create a "lookup table" for the column names where the key is the index and the value is the name of the column.

```cs
int colIdx = 0;
var columnNames = dt.Columns
    .Cast<DataColumn>()
    .ToDictionary(_ => colIdx++, column => column.ColumnName);
```

After that your foreach loop would look like this:

```cs
int[] columnIndexes = new[] {0, 1, 4};
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnIndexes.Length; columnIndex++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(columnNames[columnIndex] + " ");
        Console.WriteLine(row.ItemArray[columnIndex] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: now rather than writing the line if i wanted to store the value of the item array in a string ex:

`string toEmail = dt.Rows[idx].ItemArray[4].ToString(); 
console.writeline(toEmail);`

 once again throws that same error i encountered. because the endgame im going for is looping through this table using those 3 values to populate multiple strings that will be the to/from/body of an email

Comment: @chessmt In order to be able to help you with the error I need to see the modified code and the whole stacktrace of the exception. Please do not modify the original question's code rather open a new question and link here please.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can access [DataRow.Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=netcore-3.1#System_Data_DataRow_Item_System_String_) by their names

Answer (score 2):

Remove one of the loops:

```
                for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[0].ColumnName + " ");
                    Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[0].ToString() + " ");
                    Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[1].ColumnName + " ");
                    Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[1].ToString() + " ");
                    Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[4].ColumnName + " ");
                    Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[4].ToString() + " ");
                }
```

Or

```
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows){
                    Console.WriteLine($"{dr[0]} - {dr[1]} - {dr[4]}");
                }
```

Comment: thanks! dont know why i thought i needed two loops to get all the values

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point out that you indeed can access values in a `DataRow` by [column name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataRow_Item_System_String_). That functionality is available in full .net framework as well as .net core (so you are covered regardless of which one you use).
This of course carries a slight performance hit because it seems to end up doing a `Dictionary` lookup.

One advantage you get from taking this route is you'd be less dependant on table structure changes in future - which might be a tradeoff worth considering.

Then your intention could be expressed like so:

```cs
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    Console.WriteLine($"{row["Col0"]} - {row["Col1"]} - {row["Col4"]}");
```

now, suppose you want to drop `foreach` and and go `LINQ`:

```
void Main()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Col0", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Col4", typeof(string));
    
    dt.Rows.Add("one","two","three","four","five");
    dt.Rows.Add("ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen");

    var formattedItems = dt.Rows // declaring a lise you'd open yourself up to further processing the results rather than just pringint them
                            .Cast<DataRow>() // DataRow collection does implement IEnumerable through its base InternalDataCollectionBase class but we seem to need this cast in order to properly expose it
                            .Select(row => $"{row["Col0"]} - {row["Col1"]} - {row["Col4"]}") // and now we can unleash the LINQ
                            .ToList(); // depending on your further processing code you can either enumerate it now or have it sitting around until you actually need to loop through it
    
    Console.WriteLine(formattedItems.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, s) => sb.AppendLine(s)).ToString()); // just slapping list items together in a string to print out for your convenience
}
```