# looping through data table to get specifics values from each row

Tags: c#, datatable

when looping through this datatable im unable to use the stored values in an if else statement i get the following error
**The system cannot execute the specified program.**
what i expected to happen is the if else block to check the toValue and go from there
ps - a continuation from a prior question [looping thru datatable values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63627822/looping-through-data-table-to-get-two-specifics-values-from-each-row)
edit* added the full code block for clarity

```
 string conString = "user id =user1; password =password;" + "data source = database.home.org";

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection
        {
            ConnectionString = conString
        };

        con.Open();
       var pullRecord = new OracleCommand("select * FROM email_records", con);
        var dt= new DataTable();
        var da = new OracleDataAdapter(pullRecord);
             da.Fill(dt);

        for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
        {

            string toValue = (dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[0].ToString() + " ");
            string ccValue = (dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[1].ToString() + " ");
            string bodyValue = (dt.Rows[x].ItemArray[4].ToString() + " ");

            if(toValue == "one" || toValue == "two" || toValue == "three")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bodyValue);
            }
            else if (toValue == "four" || toValue == "five")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bodyValue);
            }
            else if (toValue == "six" || toValue == "seven")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bodyValue);
            }
            else if (toValue == "eight" || toValue == "nine")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bodyValue);
            }
            else if (toValue == "ten" || toValue == "eleven")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bodyValue);
            }
            else if (toValue == "twelve")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bodyValue);
            }
            else if (toValue == "thirteen")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bodyValue);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bodyValue);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I removed the `oracle` tag, since it seems unrelated to the question.

Comment: you are adding a blank space after your values but it seems you are matching on  meaningful strings only

Comment: @timur yeah good catch i removed the blank space but the error persists, it should only match on meaningful string otherwise trigger the final else condition correct?

Comment: the `if-statements` should do that, yes. But in your case it actually doesn't matter which one the code hits as all `Console.Writeline`s are identical

Comment: @timur as of now no, but each different hit will do something different eventually, i left it as is just to see if it works overall. but it just throws that error, even if i remove every case  but the first and make sure the value of `toValue = "one"`  it throws that error

Comment: It seems the issue is not the code you shared but rather somewhere else. We will probably need more context on how you build/run and debug your program.

Comment: @timur added full code block for clarity

Comment: yeah, as i hinted above, i don't think code is the issue - it looks like the environment. Can you rather add details on how you build/run and how exactly the error manifests itself?

Comment: @timur its built/running as a console app, if i remove the if/else block it runs fine, i can loop through that datatable and print the values without issue, once the if/else is introduced nothing runs at all, the console just writes out the error **The system cannot execute the specified program.**